# Find cardinality of a set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How to find the cardinality $|X|$ of the set $X$ given by

$$X = \{f : \{1,2,3,4\} \longrightarrow \{1,2,3,4\}\, |\, x < y \implies f(x) \leq f(y) \}\,?$$

I tried to draw a graph listing the domains and ranges $\{1,2,3,4\}$. By instinct, I tried counting manually, but surely there is a better way.

I know that the answer is $|X|=35$. I want to figure out how can I obtain the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is defined by the pairs of input and outputs it produces.

We are going to represent the function by a $4$ digit number. For example, $1244$ means the function such that $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=4, f(4)=4$.

How many functions are there starting with prefix $11$? Well, there are $4$ with the prefix $111$, plus $3$ with the prefix $112$, ... for a total of $4+3+2+1$ functions with the prefix $11$.

Similarly, there are $3+2+1$ functions with the prefix $12$, etc. Thus there are $(4+3+2+1)+(3+2+1)+(2+1)+(1)$ functions with the prefix $1$.

Following the same reasoning, there should be $(3+2+1)+(2+1)+(1)$ functions with the prefix $2$, etc.

Thus the total number of functions is
$$
(4+3+2+1)+(3+2+1)+(2+1)+(1) + \\
(3+2+1)+(2+1)+(1) + \\
(2+1)+(1) + \\
(1)=\\
\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^i\sum_ {k=1}^j k = 35
$$

Answer (score 2):

In effect you need to count the non-decreasing $4$-tuples that can be made from the numbers $1,2,3$, and $4$. More generally, let’s try to count the non-decreasing $n$-tuples that can be made from the integers $1,2,\ldots,n$.

Such an $n$-tuple is completely determined once we know how many of each integer in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ appears in it. The $4$-tuple $\langle 1,3,3,3\rangle$, for instance, is completely described by the information that it has one $1$, no $2$s, three $3$s, and no $4$s. Thus, there is a bijection between non-decreasing $n$-tuples from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $n$-tuples $\langle c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\rangle$ of non-negative integers such that

$$c_1+c_2+\ldots+c_n=n\;.\tag{1}$$

Counting the latter is a well-known problem; it can be done by the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two), which leads to the conclusion that there are

$$\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\binom{2n-1}n$$

solutions to $(1)$ in non-negative integers and hence the same number of non-decreasing $n$-tuples of integers from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. In your case that’s $\binom73=35$.

The reasoning behind this result is explained fairly well in the linked article.

Comment: I like this! Simpler than mine. +1

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Yours is a very natural way to approach the problem, though, and you can finish it off by rewriting your final summation as $\sum_{k=3}^6\binom{k}3$ and applying the hockey stick lemma to simplify it to $\binom74$.

Comment: Oh nice, I don't think I knew that. Not by the (rather curious haha) name, at least.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: You can read about it [here](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity) (among many other places), with a picture showing where the name comes from.

Comment: Oh, I understand the name now. Nice, thank you!

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: My pleasure; you’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a combinatorics problem.

Each such function can be represented in a unique manner by a quadruple $(f_1,d_2,d_3,d_4)$, where $f_1 \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $d_2,d_3,d_4 \geq 0$ are integers with $f_1+d_2+d_3+d_4\leq 4$. The corresponding function is

\begin{aligned}
f(1)&=f_1\\
f(2)&=f_1+d_2\\
f(3)&=f_1+d_2+d_3\\
f(4)&=f_1+d_2+d_3+d_4
\end{aligned}

So, it suffices to count how many such quadruples there are.

Now, we successively transform the problem of counting such quadruples into 'easier' (in some sense) problems.

The problem of solving

\begin{aligned}
d_2+d_3+d_4\leq 4-f_1&&&&&&(d_i\geq 0)
\end{aligned}

is analogous to the problem of solving

\begin{aligned}
d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5 = 4-f_1&&&&&&(d_i\geq 0)
\end{aligned}

Indeed, $d_5$ is merely the leftovers (if any) of $4-f_1-(d_2+d_3+d_4)$ in the previous problem.

Finally, this second problem is equivalent to solving

\begin{aligned}
e_2+e_3+e_4+e_5 = 8-f_1&&&&&&(e_i\geq 1)
\end{aligned}

Here, just set $e_i=d_i+1$. The problem of counting solutions for this type of equation is well known solution (see [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))), and the number of solutions is $$\binom{(8-f_1)-1}{4-1}=\binom{7-f_1}{3}$$

(the four in the binomial comes from the number of variables in the problem, the $e_i$)

Finally, we just need to sum through all of the possible values of $f_1$, so the answer is:

$$\sum_{f_1=1}^4\binom{7-f_1}{3}$$

which can be easily checked to be $35$.